# Debug a source file(and functions local to it) using GDB without stepping into Library calls?

Tags: gdb

I want to debug a program but i don't want GDB to print the code it visits out of my local source file scope. The options ***step***(goes into every call) and ***next***(skips stepping into the functions even in the same source file) aren't useful in this case.

Any points on the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can see my answer to 
[Does GDB have a “step-to-next-call” instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34621532/does-gdb-have-a-step-to-next-call-instruction/34672420#34672420)
: there is no native GDB command for that (as far as I know, they may have worked on that), but it's easy to do in Python:

```
import gdb

class StepNoLibrary (gdb.Command):
    def __init__ (self):
        super (StepNoLibrary, self).__init__ ("step-no-library",
                                              gdb.COMMAND_OBSCURE)

    def invoke (self, arg, from_tty):
        step_msg = gdb.execute("step", to_string=True)

        fname = gdb.newest_frame().function().symtab.objfile.filename

        if fname.startswith("/usr"):
            # inside a library
            SILENT=False
            gdb.execute("finish", to_string=SILENT)
        else:
            # inside the application
            print(step_msg[:-1])

    StepNoLibrary()
```

just put that in a file, source it with GDB (or in your .gdbinit) and that will provide you the new command `step-no-library`.

It's easy to read what it does, it goes one `step` forward, and if the step ends up in a file stored in `/usr/*`, it `finish`es it to come back to the application.

Of course that's a naive implementation, if you requirements are different from that just edit the function code!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using DDD(Data display debugger). Reminds alot about gdb

type in:

```
ddd --gdb
```

Then

```
g++ -O0 -g -o main main.cpp
```

Hope it might help