# Does GDB have a "step-to-next-call" instruction?

Tags: gdb

WinDBG and the related windows kernel debuggers support a "pc" command which runs the target until reaching the next call statement (in assembly).  In other words, it breaks just prior to creating a new stack frame, sort of the opposite of "finish".  "Start" in GDB runs until main starts, but in essence I want 'start' but with a wildcard of "any next frame".

I'm trying to locate a similar functionality in GDB, but have not found it.

is this possible?

Example WinDBG doc: http://windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html#4_expr_and_cmds

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Simple answer:** no, `step-to-next-call` is not part of GDB commands.

**GDB/Python-aware answer**: no, it's not part of GDB commands, but it's easy to implement!

I'm not sure to understand if you want to stop before or after the `call` instruction execution.

- To stop **before**, you need to `stepi/nexti` (next assembly instruction) until you see `call` in the current instruction:

  ```
  import gdb

  class StepBeforeNextCall (gdb.Command):
      def __init__ (self):
          super (StepBeforeNextCall, self).__init__ ("step-before-next-call",
                                                     gdb.COMMAND_OBSCURE)

      def invoke (self, arg, from_tty):
          arch = gdb.selected_frame().architecture()

          while True:
              current_pc = addr2num(gdb.selected_frame().read_register("pc"))
              disa = arch.disassemble(current_pc)[0]
              if "call" in disa["asm"]: # or startswith ?
                  break

              SILENT=True
              gdb.execute("stepi", to_string=SILENT)

          print("step-before-next-call: next instruction is a call.")
          print("{}: {}".format(hex(int(disa["addr"])), disa["asm"]))

  def addr2num(addr):
      try:
          return int(addr)  # Python 3
      except:
          return long(addr) # Python 2

  StepBeforeNextCall()
  ```
- To stop **after** the call, you compute the current stack depth, then `step` until it's deeper:

  ```
  import gdb

  def callstack_depth():
      depth = 1
      frame = gdb.newest_frame()
      while frame is not None:
          frame = frame.older()
          depth += 1
      return depth

  class StepToNextCall (gdb.Command):
      def __init__ (self):
          super (StepToNextCall, self).__init__ ("step-to-next-call", 
                                                 gdb.COMMAND_OBSCURE)

      def invoke (self, arg, from_tty):
          start_depth = current_depth =callstack_depth()

          # step until we're one step deeper
          while current_depth == start_depth:
              SILENT=True
              gdb.execute("step", to_string=SILENT)
              current_depth = callstack_depth()

          # display information about the new frame
          gdb.execute("frame 0")

  StepToNextCall()
  ```

just put that in a file, `source` it with GDB (or in your `.gdbinit`) and that will provide you the new commands `step-before-next-call` and `step-to-next-call`.

Relevant documentation is there:

- [Python API table of content](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Python-API.html)
- [Basic Python](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Basic-Python.html)
- [Python representation of architectures](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Architectures-In-Python.html)
- [Accessing inferior stack frames from Python.](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Frames-In-Python.html)