# Step to Next Branching Instruction in GDB

Tags: gdb

Is there a way to continue execution until a branching instruction is reached in GDB? Much like the WinDbg "ph" command. If not, can it be scripted in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally came across this question:

[Does GDB have a "step-to-next-call" instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34621532/does-gdb-have-a-step-to-next-call-instruction)

I was able to modify the code there to create my own "ph" command:

```py
import gdb

mips_branches = ["beq", "beqz", "bne", "bnez", "bgtz", "bltz", "bgez", "blez", "j", "jr", "jal", "jalr"]
arm_branches = ["b", "bl", "blx", "bx", "beq"]

class StepToNextBranch (gdb.Command):
    def __init__ (self):
        super (StepToNextBranch, self).__init__ ("ph", gdb.COMMAND_OBSCURE)

    def invoke (self, arg, from_tty):
        arch = gdb.selected_frame().architecture()

        while True:
            SILENT=True
            gdb.execute("nexti", to_string=SILENT)
            current_pc = int(gdb.selected_frame().read_register("pc"))
            disa = arch.disassemble(current_pc)[0]
            opcode = disa["asm"].split("\t")[0]
            if opcode in mips_branches or opcode in arm_branches:
                break

        gdb.execute("context")

StepToNextBranch()
```

I'm not as familiar with ARM as MIPS so I'm not sure this covers everything. Eventually, I'll add x86 branching instructions.

Also, that `gdb.execute("context")` line is there because I use [GEF](https://github.com/hugsy/gef).